# Excerpt vs content formatting woes

Tags: content, excerpt

One of my posts has the following content:

```
This is a test post. Nothing more,
nothing less.
Three lines before the jump
<!--more-->
And a couple of more lines
after the jump.
```

*Note*: these were written as you see them, in the WP editor, using the HTML tab - so we have no hidden `<br>` or anything else going on in the post content.

*Also*: No Manual Excerpt was defined for this post.

If I use `the_content()`, I get this:

```
<p>This is a test post. Nothing more,<br /> 
nothing less.<br /> 
Three lines before the jump</p> 
<p><a href="...#more-1336" class="more-link" title="Continue Reading">&raquo;</a></p>
```

If, however, I use `echo get_the_excerpt();` I get this:

```
This is a test post. Nothing more, nothing less. Three lines before the jump
```

No `<p>`s, nor `<br />`s (*heck*, not even the `[...]` I was half-expecting!)

What I'd really like to achieve in my theme is (within The Loop, of course):

1. If a manual excerpt exists: display
   that (and I know I'll have to tweak
   the `[...]`)
2. Else, display the
   content, respecting any
   `<!--more-->` you may find.

So, I was starting with this

```
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
if($excerpt=='') { //right, isset or empty may be better
    the_content();
} else {
    echo $excerpt;
}
```

But I'm getting the feeling there's a better way? Or is there a quick fix for the formatting issue mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the_content() and the_excerpt(), unlike their 'get_' brothers will process the content through some functions, one of them is wpautop() that will add p tags for you. To get the same formatting for both excerpt and content:

```
if ( has_excerpt() ) {
  the_excerpt();
} else {
  the_content(__('Read more'));
}
```

Comment: Lovely! Thanks for the tip (I knew of wpautop() but didn't realize it did more than enclosing in `<p>`s